# Is there some way to save an array (write file) through geth to a text file?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, javascript

I'm looking to save or extract an array inside a file.js file in geth console to a text file. I have
shearched this subject but i could find nothing related to this. Is this possible?

I tried:

```
  /.geth --jspsth"path/to/file" --exec "eth.namereg(loadScript('file.js'))" > file.txt
```

but it doesn't work.

I hope someone could help me.

Thanks